# How to return data to html field with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got various text fields with buttons beside each in a grid. When I click a button, it returns a value to a text field beside it. The problem is making it know which text field to return the data to. I've currently got it set up to pass a parameter with the function which is put into a hidden field, and a switch statement checks that field in order to know which field to send the data back to.

It works, but it seems like I should be able to do this with a lot less code, and something that isn't so statically programmed (I don't want to manually update the switch statement when I add new fields to the form). I hope there's a simple answer, I'm new to programming and anything complex I won't understand.

A simplified example of what I've got is this:

```
<form action="#" name="testForm">
    <input type="text" name="input1" size="20">
    <input type=button value="get data" onClick="populateField(1)"/>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="input2" size="20">
    <input type=button value="get data" onClick="populateField(2)"/>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="input3" size="20">
    <input type="button" value="get data" onClick="populateField(3)"/>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lineID" size=1 style="display:none"/>
</form>

<script>
    function populateField(input) {
        document.testForm.lineID.value = input;
        var element = document.getElementById("lineID");
        var lineID = element.value;
        switch (lineID) {
            case "1":
                document.testForm.input1.value = "some value";
                break;
            case "2":
                document.testForm.input2.value = "some value";
                break;
            case "3":
                document.testForm.input3.value = "some value";
            //etc
        }
    }
</script>
```

Instead of a separate case for every `"document.testForm.input#.value"`, how can I use the variable to substitute for the `"input#"`?

Comment: *Standardize your HTML:* use lowercase HTML tags please, and double quote all attribute values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```
document.testForm['input' + lineID].value
```